# Google sheets script giving me "Object does not allow properties to be added or changed" error. I suspect getRange related issue

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to make a custom trigger function that will triggered on Edit. My objective is to track when certain range of a sheet is modified or added, and capture that in another sheet by adding a string in a certain Cell.
That update mark has to be in column I, intersecting the row where the reference to the ID of the modified cell is.

Now, when I try to run it, it gives me that error, but it has no further explanation, so I have no idea how to proceed. 
Can you help me, please?
This is my code:

```js
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var e = ss.getActiveSheet()
  var ecell= e.getActiveCell()
  var allsheets = ss.getSheets();
  var version = "0.4.0";
  //Making sure that whatever was updated it is not in the first 5 columns nor in the first 2 rows
  if (e.columnStart < 5 || e.rowStart < 2 || e.getSheetName() =="0.4.0") return;
  //Trying to get hlook pointing to the F2 cell
  var hlook= e.getRange('F2');
  // Want to set up a formula in F2 so that I can get de location of the index (manual ID) value of ecell
  hlook.setFormula="HLOOKUP(ecell, 'A'+ ROW(ecell) + ':' + 'Q' + ROW(ecell),3)";
  // Want to retrieve the value returned from the formula
  var eid=hlook.getActiveCell().getValue();
  //Navigting all available sheets to set up updates
  for (var s in allsheets){
    var sheet=allsheets[s];
    // Dismissing the master sheet
    if (sheet.getSheetName()!="0.4.0")
   {
     //Assigning a variable to AA1 (or even further, whith is fine)
     var con=e.getRange(1,28);
     //Setting up a formula
     con.setFormula="IFERROR(VLOOKUP(eid, 'C1:C35',1), false)";
     // Retrieving formula result
     var control=con.getActiveCell().getValue();
     if (control!=false)
     {
       //If the value I am looking for actually existws on this sheet, enter update stamp at column I on the row where the value was found
       var ro=VLOOKUP(eid, "C1:C350",1);
       var cel="I" + ro;
       cel.setValue(version)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I believe your problem is in your .setFormula.  When you type .setFormula="...formula..."; the script thinks you want to edit the 'setFormula' object.  In fact you want to do the action, setFormula, so you should format like this:

```
hlook.setFormula("...formula...");
```

The other thing you'd want to look at is your formulas.  You'll find that once on the sheet, google sheets won't know what ecell is.  The A1 notation of ecell can be grabbed in your ecell variable using:

```
var ecell = e.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
```

Then you can substitute this into your formula like so:

```
hlook.setFormula("HLOOKUP(" + ecell + ", 'A'+ ROW(" + ecell + ") + ':' + 'Q' + ROW(" + ecell + "),3)");
```

I've just commented where to modify your code in this way in order to correct it:

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var e = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var ecell= e.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  var allsheets = ss.getSheets();
  var version = "0.4.0";
  //Making sure that whatever was updated it is not in the first 5 columns nor in the first 2 rows
```

MODIFY HERE - if statement needs {}, format if (statement) {action}  so curly brackets around {return;}

```
  if (e.columnStart < 5 || e.rowStart < 2 || e.getSheetName() =="0.4.0") return; //why not use version variable here?

  //Trying to get hlook pointing to the F2 cell
  var hlook= e.getRange('F2');
  // Want to set up a formula in F2 so that I can get de location of the index (manual ID) value of ecell
```

MODIFY SETFORMULA();

```
   hlook.setFormula="HLOOKUP(ecell, 'A'+ ROW(ecell) + ':' + 'Q' + ROW(ecell),3)";
  // Want to retrieve the value returned from the formula
```

MODIFY SCRIPT - you want the value of hlook, so

```
var eid = hlook.getValue();
*******************************
  var eid=hlook.getActiveCell().getValue();
  //Navigting all available sheets to set up updates
  for (var s in allsheets){
    var sheet=allsheets[s];
    // Dismissing the master sheet
    if (sheet.getSheetName()!="0.4.0")
   {
     //Assigning a variable to AA1 (or even further, whith is fine)
     var con=e.getRange(1,28);
     //Setting up a formula
```

MODIFY SETFORMULA();

```
     con.setFormula="IFERROR(VLOOKUP(eid, 'C1:C35',1), false)";
     // Retrieving formula result
     var control=con.getActiveCell().getValue();
     if (control!=false)
     {
       //If the value I am looking for actually existws on this sheet, enter update stamp at column I on the row where the value was found
```

MODIFY HERE -

```
var ro = "VLOOKUP(" + eid + ", "C1:C350",1)";
*******************************

       var ro=VLOOKUP(eid, "C1:C350",1);
       var cel="I" + ro;
       cel.setValue(version)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hopefully with these modifications it will work, but if you get errors please let me know I'll have another look :)  Good luck

Comment: Thank you for your time and the suggestions! I tried it, but I think I can't assign any value to a cell, so, until I find out why can't I, this project is on hold :(

Comment: Could you possibly post your latest code as an edit?  I'd be happy to look through again and potentially try to replicate your problem.  I'm not sure what you might have changed since last time.